# Consuming APIs in Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I want to use **[semantics3](https://github.com/Semantics3/semantics3-ruby)** API to list some products on my e-commerce site. It is a simple question, but I did successfully manage to use a couple of other APIs.

Here's their gem - https://github.com/Semantics3/semantics3-ruby

1. Where should I put API Credentials?
2. When I create Search controller, for example, what exactly do I put in the index method if I want to search for products and how to list the results in the index.html.erb view file?

Answer (score 0):

I would trying to put https://github.com/Semantics3/semantics3-ruby#setup-work into an initializer.

Something like this

```
require 'semantics3'

SEMANTICS = Semantics3::Products.new(ENV['SEMANTICS_API_KEY'], ENV['SEMANTICS_API_SECRET'])
```

into config/initializers/semantics.rb

and set the environment variables SEMANTICS_API_KEY and SEMANTICS_API_SECRET

Then use SEMANTICS normally in the controller

Comment: Could you give me a simple example? How do I define the index method in the SearchController and how can I list results in views/search/index.html.erb ... is this okay:                     def index
   productsHash = sem3.get_products(params[:query])
   puts productsHash.to_json
end

Comment: I will say to always sanitize your query params, ie rather than using params[:query] use a sanitizer which only takes values like params[:brand_name] and then construct the query yourself like

`SEMANTICS..products_field( "brand", params[:brand_name])`

It  would be a good idea to use a presenter .. https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_presenters

Answer (score 0):

1.) Use API credentials here

```
API_KEY = 'SEM3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'       #Use you api key here
API_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'  #Use you API secret here

#Receive data after verfiying the API credentials
sem3 = Semantics3::Products.new(API_KEY,API_SECRET)

sem3.products_field( "search", "Samsung Galaxy" )
```

2.) It would be helpful if you show me your code?